# simplification of fractions

Tags: java, fractions, simplify

The project I am currently working on calls for the program to take in two fractions, add them together and simplify the answer. I have finished add the fractions together just fine but I cannot figure out how to simplify the fractions.

P.S. everything I have seen so far so far on the topping is really confusing and it would help if you could make the answer simple 
THANKS!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class Fractions {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Numerator A");
int NuA = Scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Denominator A");
int DeA = Scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Numerator B");
int NuB = Scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Denominator B");
int DeB = Scan.nextInt();

double NumA = NuA * DeB;
double NumB = NuB * DeA;
double Denominator= DeA * DeB;

double Numerator=NumA + NumB;

}
}
```

Comment: Usually the first letter of the variable's name is lower. Scan -> scan, NumA -> numA and NumB -> numB etc.

Comment: Why do you use `double`s at all? Fractions' numerators and denominators are always integers...

Comment: What would you do on a piece of paper / in your head to simplify the fractions?

Answer (score 0):

First, remember how one reduces a fraction to lowest terms.  Given integers `a` and `b`,

```
a/b == (a/m)/(b/m)  where m is the greatest common divisor of a and b.
```

The greatest common divisor, written gcd(a, b) or just (a, b) in mathematics, is most easily obtainable by using Euclid's algorithm:

```
(111, 45) == (21, 45) since 111 = 2 * 45 + 21.
          == (45, 21)
          == (3, 21)  since 45 = 2 * 21 + 3
          == (21, 3)
          == (0, 3)   since 21 = 7 * 3 + 0.
          == 3        stop when one number is zero.
```

Now, neither `Integer` nor  `Number` nor `Math` have a `gcd` method, and you should write one yourself only if you're doing it to learn the algorithm.  However, `BigInteger` has the method.  So, create a `Fraction` class. We'll make it immutable, so we can extend `Number`, and so we should reduce it to lowest terms as we construct it.

```
public class Fraction extends Number {
    private final BigInteger numerator;
    private final BigInteger denominator;
    public Fraction(final BigInteger numerator, final BigInteger denominator) {
        BigInteger gcd = numerator.gcd(denominator);
        // make sure negative signs end up in the numerator only.
        // prefer 6/(-9) to reduce to -2/3, not 2/(-3).
        if (denominator.signum() == -1) {
             gcd = gcd.negate();
        } 
        this.numerator = numerator.divide(gcd);
        this.denominator = denominator.divide(gcd);
    }
}
```

Now, add the rest of your math routines.  Notice that I did nothing about nulls, division by zero, infinities, or NaNs.